# Textext.js - Remove all tags and clean textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-textext

i have a question, i'm using [Textext.js](http://textextjs.com/) to list users from the database, i'm using tags with custom data objects ({name: 'nameTag', id: 1}) the problem is that i need to clean the text field and the tags with a "cleanFields" button and I can not find a way to do it. This is my code:

```
$("#myTextarea").textext({
    plugins: 'tags prompt autocomplete',
    prompt: 'Add one...',
    ext: {
        itemManager: {
            items: [],
            stringToItem: function (str) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
                    if (this.items[i].name == str) {
                        id = this.items[i].id;
                        break;
                    }
                return { name: str, id: id }; //tags with custom data objects
            },
            itemToString: function (item) {
                this.items.push(item);
                return item.name;

            },
            compareItems: function (item1, item2) {
                return item1.name == item2.name;
            }
        }
    }
})
.bind('getSuggestions', function (e, data) {
    var list = f_GetListTags() //this returns the list from the database
    , textext = $(e.target).textext()[0],
        query = (data ? data.query : '') || '';
    $(this).trigger(
        'setSuggestions',
        { result: textext.itemManager().filter(list, query) }
    );
})
```

The button:

```
$("#cleanFields").click(function () {
    $('#myTextarea').val(''); //this cleans the text area

    //but i also need to remove all tags :(
});
```

Please help me! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags are stored inside a div class **.text-tags** and they have an anchor **a.text-remove** that you can use to remove them - you won't need to clear the textarea if you use this as it's part of the remove already:

```
$("#cleanFields").click(function () {
    // This will clear the text area and remove the tags :)
    $(".text-tags a.text-remove").trigger("click");
});
```

*Caution: This will clear all textareas with tags. Unless you are only using 1 tag input field, you should consider making your selectors (ids / classes) more specific to avoid conflicts.*